# Измение типа границы формы выбором RadioButton

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте,на форме расположен `GroupBox` c несколькими `RadioButton`.
Нужно по выборы соответствующей `RadioButton` изменять `BorderStyle` формы.
Если я правильно понимаю мне нужно событие `CheckedChange` для кнопок, но как мне устанавливать cтиль границы я не понимаю,подскажите,пожалуйста.Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего на каждый `RadioButton` навесить свой обработчик события и в нём задавать нужную рамку формы.

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
}
```

И так далее...

Answer (score 1):

`BorderStyle` у формы на самом деле называется `FormBorderStyle`. Изменять его, во время выполнения программы, конечно, можно, но только это мало вам чего даст на самом деле, так как мало просто поменять стиль рамки, нужно еще и создать форму заново, иначе заданный стиль не будет применен так, как предполагалось.

Вот мои [потуги](https://yadi.sk/d/8RiUkmQawizVN) в виде солюшна.

Что делаю (кратко):
На форме есть 7 радио-кнопок (именно столько стилей для формы доступно в дизайнере). Каждая радиокнопка имеет в свойстве Tag значение от 0 до 6.
Все радикнопки используют один обработчик нажатия, который определяет значение свойства Tag и в зависимости от его значения устанавливает стиль границы формы. Всё.
Так же есть вторая форма, к которой применяется выбранный стиль, но показывается она по нажатию соответствующей кнопки.

Основная логика работы происходит в обработчике нажатия на радио-кнопку:

```
        void RadioButtonSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
        int tag = -1;
        if (rb.Tag != null)
        {
            tag = Convert.ToInt32(rb.Tag);
        }

        switch (tag) 
        {
            case 0:
                _style = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                break;
            case 1:
                _style = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                break;
            case 2: 
                _style = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                break;
            case 3: 
                _style = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
                break;
            case 4:
                _style = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                break;
            case 5: 
                _style = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
                break;
            case 6:
                _style = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
                break;
            default:
                _style = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                break;
        }

        this.FormBorderStyle = _style;
        this.RecreateHandle(); //Пробую пересоздать форму с новым стилем.
    }

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormDemo demo = new FormDemo();
        demo.FormBorderStyle = _style;
        demo.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Не знаю почему, но у меня проект на Win 7 не работает так, как я от него ожидал. Да, стиль рамки меняется, но не в полной мере.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)